# Is there a way to set the default page size when printing in IE7?

Tags: printing, internet-explorer-7

I recently convinced a customer to upgrade to Internet Explorer 7 but now she is having an issue printing. When printing emails from her webmail in IE6 they would print at 75% and fit on a single page. Now with IE7 they added the "Shirnk to Fit" option which is the default. This doesn't work as expected and makes her previously 1 page emails into 2. She would prefer to not have to do a print preview of every email and adjust the print resolution so I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to set a default value for the scaling other than the "Shrink to Fit".

Answer (score 1):

You could play with the CSS settings for the media type of "print" (perhaps, just for this one customer) to resize the entire HTML by 75% or something.

(First google result for "css print" is a not-so-bad-example from [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/).)